# Pine Script Как узнать кол-во баров M5 с открытия дня по текущий момент?

Tags: pinescript

Мне нужно ограничить серию данных о цене текущим торговым днем. То есть я ожидаю увидеть в серии данные баров М5 с момента открытия дня до текущего момента.  Пожалуйста, подскажите, как посчитать нужное мне кол-во баров, чтобы передать это значение в `calc_bars_count`?

```html
request.security(syminfo.tickerid, '5', high, calc_bars_count = XXX)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если правильно понял вопрос, вот код.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Мой скрипт", overlay = true)

var cbf = 0 // Записывает значение индекса первого бара текущей сессии
if session.isfirstbar
    cbf := bar_index - 1

var lastbar = 0 // Записывает значение индекса текущего бара
if barstate.islast
    lastbar := bar_index

sumb = lastbar - cbf // Разница значений

sumb_5min = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, '5', sumb) // Запрос данных с 5 минут

if barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index, high, text='5min бар №' + str.tostring(sumb_5min), textcolor=color.white, color=color.black, size=size.normal) // Метка на графике с № запрошенного бара
```

Comment: Великолепно! Спасибо, брат!